# Winform BindingNavigator not saving item to database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have designed a WinForm which is bound to my database using ADO.Net Entity Framework. On load my details form is populated with data from the database.

I can navigate through the items, however I can not add, save or update the item.

Below is the code for my form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    cpdEntities dbcontext;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbcontext = new cpdEntities();
        cpd_recipientsBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.cpd_recipients.ToList();
    }


    private void cpd_recipientsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbcontext = new cpdEntities();
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what version of EntityFramwework?

Comment: see my answer. try to understand. its hard to code(format) without the IDE of Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example working with `EntityFramework 4`

How to Load:

```
 using (var con = new cpdEntities())
 {
    cpd_recipientsBindingSource.DataSource = con.cpd_recipients.ToList();
 }
```

How to Insert and Update:

```
   if (cpd_recipientsBindingSource.Current == null) return;
        using (var con = new cpdEntities())
        {

            var p = new Customer()
            {
                CustomerId = ((cpd_recipients)cpd_recipientsBindingSource.Current).Id,
                CustomerIdNo = IdNoTextBox.Text,
                CustomerName = CustomerNameTextBox.Text
            };

            var cus = new Customer();
            if (p.CustomerId > 0)
                cus = con.Customers.First(c => c.CustomerId == p.CustomerId);
            cus.CustomerId = p.CustomerId;
            cus.CustomerIdNo = p.CustomerIdNo;
            cus.CustomerName = p.CustomerName;

            if (p.CustomerId == 0)
                con.Customers.AddObject(cus);
            con.SaveChanges();
            int i = cus.CustomerId;//SCOPE_IDENTITY
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your re-instantiating your DbContext class in each of the events.  Remove re-insantiating the DbContext from your saveItem event and give it a try again.

Comment: I have removed the re-instantiating but still not saving.